# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Final Draft to change an element into a dialogue?

Tags: editing, software

In Final Draft, when I paste in text into the editor, it defaults to an action.

If I select the text or put my cursor on a spot in the text, I can go to the menu and choose "Format > Change Element to > Dialogue". There is also a dropdown menu at the top of the editor that does this.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that will let me do this?

Comment: @F1Krazy Is this appropriate place to ask this question? I didn't see a FInal Draft tag.

Comment: Questions about the use of writing software are on-topic here, yes. We have tags for [tag:scrivener] and [tag:microsoft-word], so I'm guessing we simply haven't received enough Final Draft questions to warrant one.